# Propel. how to filter a column via another one

Tags: symfony, propel

```
$books = BookGenreQuery::create()->filterByTransliteratedName($genre)
    ->joinBookGenreToBook()
    ->useBookGenreToBookQuery()
    //-> how to filter by BookGenreToBook.BookGenreId column though BookGenre.Id here?
    ->endUse()
    ->toString();
```

So how to do it?

Comment: You should add more information like your schema.xml or a other representation of your relations/tables.

Comment: Hi @Razip.  Don't you want to share your solution, for the benefit of those who might experience a similar problem or find this when questions when they search?

Comment: @Boodaleh, I'm not sure that the solution will be helpfull for them.